# i can't upload files to firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have uploaded the photos on the user's phone to firebase with UIImagePickerController, but using UIdocumentPickerController, I load pdf and similar formats, but it loads an empty file and when I try to download the files I have uploaded, it downloads an empty file- I am new to Swift, can anyone help?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MobileCoreServices
class DocViewController: UIViewController & UIDocumentPickerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate{
@IBOutlet weak var docImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let hideKeyboardGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboardGesture)
    docImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let docGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectDocument))
    docImage.addGestureRecognizer(docGestureRecognizer)
}
@objc func hideKeyboard(){
    view.endEditing(true)
}
@objc func selectDocument(){
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .open)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    documentPicker.directoryURL = .documentsDirectory
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func alertFunc(titleInput:String, messageInput: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func uploadClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageReference = storage.reference()
    let newData = Data()
    let newUuid = UUID().uuidString
    let mediaFolder = storageReference.child("Documents")
    let newDocumentReference = mediaFolder.child("\(newUuid).pdf")
    newDocumentReference.putData(newData, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
     if error != nil {
     self.alertFunc(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error!!!")
     } else{
     newDocumentReference.downloadURL { url, error in
     if error == nil{
     let documentUrl = url?.absoluteString
     let documentFirestore = Firestore.firestore()
     var documentFirestoreReference : DocumentReference? = nil
     let firestorePost = ["imageUrl": documentUrl!, "PostedBy": Auth.auth().currentUser!.email!, "Date": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()] as [String : Any]
     documentFirestoreReference = documentFirestore.collection("Documents").addDocument(data: firestorePost, completion: { error in
     if error != nil {
     self.alertFunc(titleInput: "Error!!!", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error!!!")
     } else {
     self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
     }
     })
     }
     }
     
     }
     }
    
}

    
}
```

Comment: You're uploading newData, which you initialised as a new instance of type Data so it's going to be empty. You're not actually uploading your document, you're uploading empty data. The PDF that's being picked is also not being saved anywhere. Refer to Apple's Documentation - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories to get the file and save it to a local variable. Then, upload that variable instead, not newData.

Comment: As you said, I am sending an empty data, the videos I researched were always made with SwiftUI and this confused me a bit, I try with the putFile method as in the firebase documents, but I still fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to people who tried to help.
I solved it like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MobileCoreServices

class DocViewController: UIViewController & UIDocumentPickerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var docImage: UIImageView!
    var docUrl : URL? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let hideKeyboardGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboardGesture)
        docImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let docGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectDocument))
        docImage.addGestureRecognizer(docGestureRecognizer)
        
        
    }
   
    @objc func hideKeyboard(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    @objc func selectDocument(){
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeItem)], in: .open)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func alertFunc(titleInput:String, messageInput: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        docUrl = urls.first
        docImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.icloud.fill")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func uploadClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        docUrl!.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() //this is important for not getting permission error 
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: docUrl!)
        docUrl!.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageReference = storage.reference()
        let newUuid = UUID().uuidString
        let documentFolder = storageReference.child("Documents")
        let fileExtension = docUrl!.pathExtension
        let fileReference = documentFolder.child("\(newUuid).\(fileExtension)")
        fileReference.putData(data) { metadata, error in
            if error != nil {
                self.alertFunc(titleInput: "Error!!!", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            } else {
                fileReference.downloadURL { url, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        let documentUrl = url?.absoluteString
                        let documentFirestore = Firestore.firestore()
                        var documentFirestoreReference : DocumentReference? = nil
                        let firestorePost = ["imageUrl": documentUrl!, "PostedBy": Auth.auth().currentUser!.email!, "Date": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()] as [String : Any]
                        documentFirestoreReference = documentFirestore.collection("Posts").addDocument(data: firestorePost, completion: { error in
                            if error != nil {
                                self.alertFunc(titleInput: "Error2!!!", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error2!!!")
                            } else {
                                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // - Use below to save a file from your local bundle
    guard let localFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YourFileName", withExtension: ".pdf") else {
        return
    }
    
    //  - Use below to save an image from your image library
    let imageData = image.pngData() or image.jpegData()
    
    // - Then save it as data rather than saving an empty data to your Firebase storage
    
    do {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: localFileURL)
    } catch (let error) {
        print("Error in \(#function) : \(error.localizedDescription) \n---\n \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Where should I write your code? because I wrote the code you sent inside the uploadClicked button and it didn't send any data this time.

Comment: Can you please show me what you wrote in your uploadClicked action?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).